How to Replace the Default HTML of wp-login.php Page in WordPress Without Creating a Custom Login Page and Redirecting to It
I'm developing a WordPress plugin that aims to modify the HTML structure of the login page (wp-login.php), registration page (wp-login.php?action=register), and lost password page (wp-login.php?action=lostpassword).
My goal is NOT to create a custom login page and redirect to it. I want to directly replace the HTML of the default WordPress login pages with my own custom HTML, without relying on redirects.
I've tried using hooks like login_enqueue_scripts to inject CSS and JavaScript, but this doesn't allow me to fully control the HTML structure.
Is there a way to achieve this?
I understand that directly modifying the HTML of core WordPress files is generally discouraged due to security and maintainability concerns. I'm open to any alternative solutions, even if they require a more complex approach.
I'm looking for any suggestions or pointers that might help me achieve this functionality.
Example:
Ideally, I'd like to replace the default WordPress login form with a custom form that has a different layout and additional fields.
Please note: I'm looking for solutions that do not involve creating custom login pages or redirecting users.
Any insights or code examples would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

You can insert your own javascript and css to completely redo the login page. Use the login_enqueue_scripts hook for that.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/login_enqueue_scripts/

Short of creating your own login page you will not be able to completely control the default login HTML, some of it is hard-coded into the template. However, you can change the presentation and DOM by using CSS and JS via the login_enqueue_scripts hook, and I think this is the most common method. I would encourage you to read through the core login file, and instead of making it behave how you want it to, see if you can adapt your outcome to what is already there.
